# How to start dynamically loading JS before DOM is ready?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

I'm trying to dynamically load an external JS file as soon as possible, but I'm observing that the file starts loading only once all of the initial scripts have been loaded (both in Chrome and FF). Is there a way to start the dynamic load before that?

I've tried both Webpack dynamic imports and manually creating the `<script>` tag in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content). Simply:

`import (/* webpackPreload: true */ 'myOtherBlah')`